# How do I affect object values stored on localStorage without overwriting them?

Tags: javascript, html

In summary, I need to make a script to take in an user rating (from 1 to 10), calculate the average rating from all entered ratings, display it on the page and, finally, make it persistent within the browser's localStorage.

As of now, I've got most of it to work. In one session, I can input as many votes as I want and have the page display the average rating, and it even persists between refreshes, since I store all required data (latest rating, sum of all ratings, number of ratings and the average rating) in an object and send it to the browser's localStorage. However, if I input a rating after refreshing, the previous object will be overwritten in the localStorage.

My question is, how do I store all said values within localStorage, and be able to keep on adding new ratings to this object without overwriting it?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Teste Formulário</title>
        <script>
            onload = () => {
                let valNota=0,valNotaTotal=0,contClicks=1,valNotaMedia=0,doMedia;
                let notaFinal=document.getElementById("notaMedia"); // this will tag the HTML element to which the average will be displayed once calculated
                let showNota;
                
                if(localStorage.getItem('notaAtual'))
                    {
                        showNota = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notaAtual'));
                        notaFinal.innerHTML=showNota.notaMedia.toFixed(1);
                    }// this will check if there is a value for the average within the localStorage object, then display it on the appropriate HTML element.
    
                btnSub.onclick = () => {
                    doMedia=1;
                    if (nota1.checked == true)
                        valNota=+nota1.value;
                    else if (nota2.checked == true)
                        valNota=+nota2.value;
                    else if (nota3.checked == true)
                        valNota=+nota3.value;
                    else if (nota4.checked == true)
                        valNota=+nota4.value;
                    else if (nota5.checked == true)
                        valNota=+nota5.value;
                    else if (nota6.checked == true)
                        valNota=+nota6.value;
                    else if (nota7.checked == true)
                        valNota=+nota7.value;
                    else if (nota8.checked == true)
                        valNota=+nota8.value;
                    else if (nota9.checked == true)
                        valNota=+nota9.value;
                    else if (nota10.checked == true)
                        valNota=+nota10.value;
                    else
                    {
                        doMedia=0;
                    } // this whole block checks for what value the rating was when the button was pressed
                     
                     
                    if (doMedia==1) // will check if there was a rating selected when the button was pressed
                    {
                        let notaData = 
                        {
                            nota: valNota, // current rating
                            notaTotal: valNotaTotal+=valNota, // total ratings (for avg calculation)
                            qtdNotas: contClicks++, // number of ratings
                            notaMedia: valNotaMedia=valNotaTotal/(contClicks-1) // average ratings
                        } // creates the object with all important variables. I am aware that the problem lays within this attribution, since it will start from 0 when I refresh the page, thus sending a brand new object to localStorage.

                        localStorage.setItem('notaAtual',JSON.stringify(notaData)); // stringifies notaData for storaging
                        showNota = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notaAtual'));
                        notaFinal.innerHTML=showNota.notaMedia.toFixed(1); // updates average within the HTML element
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div style="background:cyan;width:500px;padding:20px;">
        <p>
            Nota:
            <input type="radio" id="nota1" name="nota" value="1" />
            <label for="nota1">1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="nota2" name="nota" value="2" />
            <label for="nota2">2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="nota3" name="nota" value="3" />
            <label for="nota3">3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="nota4" name="nota" value="4" />
            <label for="nota4">4</label>
            <input type="radio" id="nota5" name="nota" value="5" />
            <label for="nota5">5</label>
            <input type="radio" id="nota6" name="nota" value="6" />
            <label for="nota6">6</label>
            <input type="radio" id="nota7" name="nota" value="7" />
            <label for="nota7">7</label>
            <input type="radio" id="nota8" name="nota" value="8" />
            <label for="nota8">8</label>
            <input type="radio" id="nota9" name="nota" value="9" />
            <label for="nota9">9</label>
            <input type="radio" id="nota10" name="nota" value="10" />
            <label for="nota10">10</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" id="btnSub">Enviar</button>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div style="background:coral;padding:20px;width:500px">
    <p>
        Nota Média: <span id="notaMedia"></span> 
    </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) load from localStorage into suitable variable, like array 2) append to array 3) store array in localStorage

Answer (score 0):

The localstorage API does not have anything like "append" or "update." You'll need to read localstorage, deserialize the value into a data structure like an object or array, mutate that data structure (add or remove a value from it), reserialize it, then store it again.

If you do this every time you add a rating, then your data should persist between refreshes.